# How can I achieve an actionbar SearchView like Gmail

Tags: android

On gmail when you click the search button the actionbar turns white and there is a dropdown of previous searches.

This is not what you get with SearchView as a menu item. Is there a library or something similar to acheive this?

```
 <item
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/search_hint"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_head_search24"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to follow [this](http://developer.android.com/training/search/setup.html) tutorial.

Basically, add it to your menu:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/search"
          android:title="@string/search_title"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
          android:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
          android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />
</menu>
```

and then, create a searchable configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:hint="@string/search_hint" />
```

with, in your activity:

```
<activity ... >
...
<meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
        android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
```

and setup the menu:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);

    // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
    SearchManager searchManager =
           (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView =
            (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(
            searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

    return true;
}
```

To make the activity that will receive the result of the search:

```
<activity android:name=".SearchResultsActivity" ... >
    ...
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
    </intent-filter>
    ...
</activity>
```

In your activity:

```
public class SearchResultsActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        handleIntent(getIntent());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        ...
        handleIntent(intent);
    }

    private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {

        if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
            //use the query to search your data somehow
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Edited with implementation details

Comment: Yup, saw that, removed my 1st comment and upvoted. Thanks for the extra effort ;-)

Comment: Thanks. I followed this but nothing happens when I search, SearchResultsActivity doesnt get launched. Any idea why?

Comment: Have you added an intent filter in your SearchResultsActivity?

Comment: Yes i have declared it in the manifest  <activity android:name="mypackage.SearchResultsActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

Comment: And you're having something in your logcat? I followed this tutorial a couple of days ago and it worked well for me

Comment: I have almost the same thing as the tutorial, the only difference is that i am using appCompat so I have the following in my menu item             app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
did you use app compat? also there is nothing in the logcat

Comment: No, I used normal SearchView, but I don't think that's the problem. can you (just for testing) increase your minSDK and use the latest SearchView just to see if that's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

One other thing you can do is implement the following:

```
implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener, SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener
```

In your activity.You will have to define some methods based on the interface but it will make for a more robust experience.

```
@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String arg0) {

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    //Create the search view
    SearchView searchView = new SearchView(this);
    searchView.setQueryHint("Search for Tracks...");
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);

    menu.add("Search")
        .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_search)
        .setActionView(searchView)
        .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```